# iphone NSMutableArray loses objects at end of method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsmutablearray

in my app, an NSMutableArray is populated with an object in viewDidLoad (eventually there will be many objects but I'm just doing one til I get it working right). I also start a timer that starts a method that needs to access the NSMutableArray every few seconds. The NSMutableArray works fine in viewDidLoad, but as soon as that method is finished, it loses the object.

myApp.h

```
@interface MyApp : UIViewController {

    NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
    NSTimer *timer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myMutableArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;
@end
```

myApp.m

```
#import "MyApp.h"

@implementation MyApp
@synthesize myMutableArray;

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    cycleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(newCycle) userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
MyObject *myCustomUIViewObject = [[MyObject alloc]init];
[myMutableArray addObject:myCustomUIViewObject];
[myCustomUIViewObject release];
NSLog(@"%i",[myMutableArray count]);  /////outputs "1"
}

-(void) newCycle {
    NSLog(@"%i",[myMutableArray count]);  /////outputs "0" ?? why is this??

}
```

Comment: Where did you alloc/init myMutableArray?  It would help to see that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

myApp.m is not retaining the array unless you assign to it using `self.myMutableArray`, unless you use the `self.` prefix you do not get the benefit of the `(nonatomic, retain)`.

Your results point to an array that is not allocated at the time you read from it. It's either this or failing to allocate the array before using `addObject` (unlikely given your NSLog result).

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    self.myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    ...
}
```

would probably fix this up.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  cycleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(newCycle) userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
  MyObject *myCustomUIViewObject = [[MyObject alloc]init];

  NSMutableArray *my_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
  self.myMutableArray = my_array;
  [my_array release];

  [myMutableArray addObject:myCustomUIViewObject];
  [myCustomUIViewObject release];
  NSLog(@"%i",[myMutableArray count]);  /////outputs "1"
```

}

and don't forget to

```
- (void) viewDidUnLoad {
  self.myMutableArray = nil;
}
```

and

```
- (void) dealloc{
  [myMutableArray release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```